# Which of the following is a vector in null A, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\6&8\\\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, span

Which of the following is a vector in null A, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\6&8\\\end{bmatrix}$

$$\begin{bmatrix}4&-3\end{bmatrix}^T$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&2\end{bmatrix}^T$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&-4\end{bmatrix}^T$$

I was wondering is there a certain formula on how to solve this.I'm reading my textbook under the subspaces and spanning but i cannot find any example relating to this question

Comment: By definition, the null space of $A$ consists of those vectors $X$ such that $AX=0$. Just multiply each of your possibilities with $A$ and see if the result of any of them is the zero vector!

Comment: Or solve the system $3x + 4y = 0 \quad 6x + 8y = 0$.

Comment: Oh thank you both @HenningMakholm and pjs36

Comment: You can find a basis for the null space of a matrix via row-reduction, but for this problem it’s easy enough to multiply each of the vectors in turn.